# I've lost my buttons on SO

Tags: bug, design, browser-support

Using Internet Explorer 9 (I know, I know :P) I've lost the formatting buttons above the answer box in Stack Overflow. They are there in Firefox, and here on Meta I can see them as well with IE9, but not on SO.

`<div id="wmd-button-bar" class="wmd-button-bar">` should have list tags inside it (at least in FF it has), but in IE9 it's completely empty.

Is it a bug or has SO secretly started to discourage the use of older browsers?

Comment: Or, you know, older browsers fail to keep up with specifications. :P

Comment: Since IE11 is out, IE9 is officially not supported anymore...

Comment: I use IE 8 at work, it is like caveman days

Answer (score 13):

(Un)fortunately, [IE 9 is no longer in the list of supported browsers on SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported). You should use versions 10 or 11 if you continue to use Internet Explorer.

Comment: I like this answer, but it needs less `(Un)`.

Comment: It would be even better with less `9`.

Comment: … or don't use IE

Comment: Even Microsoft has had enough with IE.  They are replacing it with a [new browser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Edge)

Comment: @NathanOliver Realistically it's just IEv2... look carefully at the icon of Microsoft Edge :P